# In Flutter, how to reduce the image data before saving it to a file?

Tags: flutter, image, resize, scale

I'm working on a screen recording app in Flutter. In order to keep the quality of the captured screen image, I have to scale the image as shown below. However, it makes the image data very large. How can I reduce the data size (scale back to the original size) before saving it to a file? For performance reasons, I want to work with raw RGBA instead of encoding it PNG.

```
double dpr = ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
    final boundary =
        key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
         return getBufferSync(key);
    }


       ui.Image image = boundary.toImageSync(pixelRatio: dpr);
var rawBytes = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
    Uint8List uData = rawBytes!.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Comment: tried smaller `pixelRatio`?

Comment: No, image quality is bad with smaller pixelRatio.  That's why I have to scale it to the dpr.

Comment: if you want smaller size the only way is to reduce the image quality (or encode it to different format - not rgba)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I need to capture the screen for every frame refresh. Encoding to PNG crashes the app. Low ratio makes the images not look so great. Maybe I have to create an isolate to compress the data outside the capturing isolate.

Comment: here is the link about low quality and the solution is to scale dpr but it makes image too big. [Image recorded using PictureRecoder has poor quality #98953](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98953)

Comment: ok, what you see if you `print(image)`  in both cases: `pixelRatio: dpr` and for example `pixelRatio: dpr / 2`? and how it results in `uData.length` (also in both cases)?

Comment: dpr=3 [1080×2088, 9020160] dpr=1 [432×836 1444608] dpr=1/2 [216×418 361152].   Low dpr value gives low image quality. They said that the canvas coming with `custompaint` is already scaled and it is scaled back at Layer 3. In order to produce original image quality when using `toImage`, we have to scale it to device dpr.

Comment: as you can see if you use dpr 1 the data length is exactly 4 times bigger than for dpr 1/2 - it is expected behaviour for argb images and you cannot do anything with that: n times bigger image, n*n bigger data

Comment: Thanks. I guess that there is no way that I can capture a widget(screen) image with the same size and quality as the original image in Flutter.